# How do I attach a converter to this (short-hand?) binding?

Tags: wpf

I have a `ContentPresenter` that features this binding:

```xml
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
```

Adding a converter like so fails:

```xml
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource DummyConverter}}"/>
```

Error: `The character "," is unexpected at this position.`

This might be a stupid question but I couldn't find an answer: Is `{Binding}` short for anything (so that I can attach a converter to the full expression)? If not, how do I attach a converter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may either just drop the comma:

```xml
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DummyConverter}}"/>
```

or explicitly set the Path to the source object:

```xml
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=.,
                                    Converter={StaticResource DummyConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: That was way too easy not to be embarassing. Thank you!